# Angular $http called from service, 'then' is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have seen this question many times but I can't figure out why one of my controller functions (controller 1) works fine and one (controller 2) doesn't.

Controller 1:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl1',function($scope,MyFactory)) {

  //This function works great
  MyFactory.deleteItem(item.id).then(function(response) {
    //woot woot I am here and I am fine
  });
}); //end controller 1
```

Controller 2:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl2',function($scope,MyFactory)) {

 //Function #2 that doesn't work ... 'then' is undefined
  MyFactory.createItem(item).then(function(response) {
    //booo hooo I never get here and I am definitely not fine
  });
}); //end controller 2
```

The factory:

```
.factory("MyFactory", function($http) {

var service = [];

service.deleteItem = function(itemId) {
  return $http({
    method: "delete",
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    params: //valid params go here
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log("DELETING!!!!");
    return response.data;
  });
}

service.createItem = function(post) {
  return $http({
      url: '?create',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: payload //an object
    }).then(function(response){      
      console.log(response.data); //we are fine here. there is a valid response 
      return response.data; 
   });
}
return service;
}); //end factory
```

The error thrown when executing '`createItem`' is '`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`'  What am I missing ?

Comment: use `$promise.then(function() { ...` it will definately work

Comment: also u can use success and error function

Comment: I did try success and error..no difference.

Comment: This also did not work:     `var promise = MyFactory.createItem(item);
    promise.then(function(response) {
      //booo this didnt work either
    });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the return in the `createItem` statement:

```
service.createItem = function(post) {
   return $http({
      url: '?create',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: payload //an object
    }).then(function(response){      
      console.log(response.data); //we are fine here. there is a valid response 
      return response.data; 
   });
}
```

Without it, there is no return value (which is undefined) on which you can't chain the `.then`.

Comment: Thank you...that was true. But still getting undefined ??

Comment: @lilbiscuit Hehe.. happens to all.

Comment: OK I removed the console.log and the function appears to work. But why ?

Comment: The console.log has nothing to do with it. You needed a `return` of the `$http`, that's what was missing. all console.log does it print to your dev console.

Answer (score -2):

If you are not returning `$http` the use like this :

```
$http({
  url: '?create',
  method: 'post',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: payload //an object
}).$promise.then(function(response){      
  console.log(response.data); 
  return response.data; 
});
```

Comment: This is not a negative part of answer , it will also work

Comment: `$promise` is not a property returned by the `$http` service. You are confusing `$resource` objects with `$http` promises.